# cannot change seaborn regplot regression line size?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The usual `width=10` does not work for the regplot I can change the scatter size if it was turned on however its just the regression line size/width that I am attempting to change.

I have checked the documentation and cannot find any parameters which will do this. I am sure its a simple fix just cannot seemed to find it ?

Other parameters I have attempted are as follows

```
scatter_kws={"linewidth": 10}
linewidth=10
s=10
sizes=(10, 20)
```

Admittedly most of my attempts would only work for the scatterplot but just to be clear on what I have dune already.

Thank you

```
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "y": [10, 30, 60, 90, 60, 30]})
sns.regplot(x="x", y="y", data=df, ci=65,scatter=False)
sns.lineplot(x="x", y="y", data=df)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `line_kws`, which is in the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) but a bit hidden:

> {scatter,line}_kws: dictionaries
>
> Additional keyword arguments to pass to plt.scatter and plt.plot.

```
sns.regplot(x="x", y="y", data=df, ci=65,scatter=False, line_kws={'linewidth':10})
```

[image]